# Getting Error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" while rendering image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am a newbie in react and trying to make a Book project. But the react app cant load the images of the book.
This is the directory tree:
[image: Dir tree]

This is my app.jsx:

```js
import "./App.css";

import data from "./data";

export default function BookList() {
  return (
    <section className="book-list">
      {data.map((book) => {
        const { id, title, author, imageLink } = book;
        return <Book book={book} />;
      })}
    </section>
  );
}

function Book(props) {
  const { id, title, author, imageLink } = props.book;
  console.log(id, title, author, imageLink);
  return (
    <article className="book">
      <h4>{id}</h4>
      <img src={imageLink} alt="" />
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <h4>{author}</h4>
    </article>
  );
}
```

This is a format of data.js:

```json
export default [
  {
    author: "Chinua Achebe",
    country: "Nigeria",
    imageLink: "./assets/images/things-fall-apart.jpg",
    language: "English",
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart\n",
    pages: 209,
    title: "Things Fall Apart",
    year: 1958,
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    author: "Hans Christian Andersen",
    country: "Denmark",
    imageLink: "./assets/images/fairy-tales.jpg",
    language: "Danish",
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_Tales_Told_for_Children._First_Collection.\n",
    pages: 784,
    title: "Fairy tales",
    year: 1836,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    author: "Dante Alighieri",
    country: "Italy",
    imageLink: "./assets/images/the-divine-comedy.jpg",
    language: "Italian",
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy\n",
    pages: 928,
    title: "The Divine Comedy",
    year: 1315,
    id: 2,
  },
..............
```

And this is the error message in the browser:
[image: error message and output]

The browser says nothing to preview:
[image: nothing to preview]

**Is there something that I missed ?**

Answer (score 0):

Moved the **Images** file inside **public** dir (of course changed the src) and it started working.